# Why is my mint plant growing like this?

Tags: mint

[image]Hi, I bought a mint plant from Walmart, figuring I can repot it and make it grow bigger. However it just keeps growing taller. I have 6-7” of just stem, with leaves on top. How/where should I trim it to make it bushier/fuller please?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with both previous answers - your mint needs a lot more daylight. that's why it's getting tall and lanky, shortage of light. They really prefer full sun but also grow well in partial shade (so half a day's sun). Find a bigger pot with drainage holes, only one size bigger, move it into that using fresh potting soil, water it well and allow to drain down freely. Then cut it down to about 2 inches and stand in well lit place, like a windowsill with good daylight and preferably some sun. Water when the surface of the soil feels just about dry to the touch, water thoroughly and empty any outer tray or pot after 30 minutes so it's not left sitting in water.

Answer (score 2):

Liza, it appears to me that your plant needs more sun exposure. Try putting the plant near an east facing window if possible. In the more northern latitudes, a south window has worked best for me (44 degrees north).

Comment: It looks like there are at least two separate plants in one pot. Disentangling the roots and putting them in two pots would help. As for "trimming" it, mint will regrow from the roots whatever you do to it. The usual problem growing it outdoors is how to keep it under control, not how to keep it alive!

Answer (score 2):

I also would suggest you upgrade the plant to a bigger pot (one size bigger) or put it in the ground if possible--not sure if this is an options for you. The plant is most likely root bound and there is probably a lack of nutrients in the soil. Lastly a bit of sunlight would help as in the previous comment. Mint likes partial shade to full sun. Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much, I appreciate the community help!